# Layer to KML using ArcGIS Pro doesn't show all points

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, kml, group-layer, layer-to-kml

I'm using ArcGIS Pro, and I am trying to convert a group of layer (both points) to KML. When I make the KML and open it it doesn't show all the points!
[image]

Comment: The yellow one is selected or in a different layer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a tool to operate on every feature in a layer, always unselect selected features before using a tool in ArcGIS. If any feature is selected, the tool uses only selected ones.

Comment: Yes, I unselect all features then I use geoprocessing tools.

Answer (score 2):

I am uncertain if you can convert a group. I believe you have to convert the layer's separately.
Layer to KML is the tool unless I am unaware of another tool that states multiple layers to kml.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it gives me a good result, but sometimes it gives me a result with missing points.